# Cordova file plugin return an error with code: 12, PATH_EXISTS_ERR only on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm writing a simple app in Ionic 3, for submitting forms with few attachments (picture from the camera, picture from gallery and one 20 s movie). After form submits into the server, forms are processing and receiving statuses. Statuses are fetching through the app to inform the user. The whole form which was submitted is saving into SQLite to allow the user an access to all his forms and attachments (pictures and movies). For this purpose, I'm copying pictures and movie into Cordova file plugin:

```
let imageData = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
let dir = imageData.split('/');
let fileName = dir[dir.length - 1];
dir.pop();
let fromDirectory = dir.join('/');
let toDirectory: string = this.file.syncedDataDirectory;
await this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory, fileName, toDirectory, fileName);
```

My camera options:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    }
```

Everything is working on Android but on iOS I'm receiving an error with code: 12, PATH_EXISTS_ERR. Error occurs only with pictures. I'm copying the movie in the same way as pictures:

```
await this.file.copyFile(fromDirectory, movieName, toDirectory, movieName)
```

In the first session, I'm adding one picture from the camera and one from the gallery (Camera Roll), and all is working fine. The problem occurs in a new session when I'm trying to add other pictures. If I added two pictures in the previous session, in the second session I receive twice error: PATH_EXISTS_ERR, and third approach to adding a picture is a success. It looks like in one session file plugin is writing picture with index 001, 002 etc... But in new session file plugin is trying to write a new picture again with index 001, but this path already exists.
I can not find any replication of this error, probably I'm using file plugin in the wrong way, but on Android, everything is working perfectly with the same way of copying the file into file plugin (one except I'm copying files into this.file.dataDirectory). If I will not find a solution probably I will transform pictures into base64 and I will store them as a string.
I will be really grateful for any advice!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, sometime it works sometimes it returns error code 12. the FILE_URI and storage paths are correct, works on Android. what's happening on iOS? anyone care to suggest a fix?

Comment: @Nexus I'm did realize that on iOS this.camera.getPicture(options) method is giving a name to file, like 001, 002 and so on. The solution was to give a unique fileName. I'm using for these Date.getTime() method.

Comment: Fantastic! Yup I figured this out a few days ago. The problem was an existing file with the same name, used a unique ID and voila, resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @Nexus I'm glad I could help.